# Sum of lengths of a line segment in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to find the total of the lengths of the line segments between consecutive elements.How can I check if there is only one point and return 0.0 as the output.I am also getting indentation errors when I am executing the above code.

```
lengthSum :: Floating a => [(a, a)] -> a
lengthSum pts = zipWith (sqrt (x'*x' + y'*y')) pts $ tail pts
    where 
        x' = fst(pts) - fst(head(tail(pts)))
        y' = snd(pts) - snd(head(tail(pts)))

Input: lengthSum [(0, 0)]
Expected Output: 0.0
Input: lengthSum [(0, 0), (0, 1), (3, 5)]
Expected Output: 7.0
```

Please can anyone help me I am newbie in haskell

Comment: I do not get indentation errors when I copy, paste and load your code. That almost always is a sign that you are mixing spaces and tabs. If that is indeed the case, replace all tabs in your code with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually add up the zipped list; `sum` will automatically handle the empty list. `zipWith` will return an empty list if `pts` has only one item, since `tail pts` will be empty. You do, however, need to treat an empty input separately. (I've defined a helper function, using pattern matching, to simplify the code a little).

```
lengthSum :: Floating a => [(a,a)] -> a
lengthSum [] = 0
lengthSum pts = sum $ zipWith distance pts (tail pts)
  where distance (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = sqrt ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.That is really helpful :)